# Change origin of collections

Tags: origin, collections

I am trying to animate a fbx imported file originally made in solidworks, since it was made in solidworks all the parts are in different layers. In order to change the rotation pivot I need to change the origin however nothing happends when I try going the object/set origin route.

Is there a way to change the origin of collections or merge a collection to a single object so I can change the origin?

There are serveral hundreds of subcollections so I cannot select them individually.

[image]

Comment: https://blenderartists.org/t/collection-utilities-addon/1229359

Answer (score 0):

The only way I think you can solve that is by pressing alt-p to clear parent and keep transformation then set the origin to geometry, after that you are free to delete the useless empty and start animating.

Comment: Okay this removed all the layers but I'm still not sure how to set the origin to where I want (I am very new to blender).

Here is an image for the part i want to rotate, I want the pivot point to be the hinge but now it is the center of the selected parts.

https://i.imgur.com/gzyo0oj.jpg